# Is this a table for a group $(G, \star)$?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

***Is the following a table for a group $(G,\star)$?
$$\begin{array}{c|ll}{\star} & {e} & {a} \\ \hline e & {e} & {e} \\ {a} & {e} & {e}\end{array}$$***

I can not see what's wrong. It's just a group with two neutral elements. Since there is only one neutral element in a group then $e=a$.

I know it's not a table for are group but I can not pinpoint the reason.

Kind regards,
X

Comment: Inverses${}{}$?

Comment: I have looked a that. But since $a=e$ then it's OK (?)

Comment: If it is, which one is the identity? What are the inverses? Does $\star$ associates?

Comment: @Arthur, I'm not sure what you mean by " artificially inflated"?

Comment: If you have a set $\{a,e\}$ where a=e, then $\{a,e\}=\{e\}$. So your group is really the trivial group with only one element, the neutral element.

Comment: The elements in a group are assumed to be different. So $G=\{e,e\}$ is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

What is the identity element of this group? You need one before you can even talk about inverses.

Comment: The identity element is $e=a$.

Comment: No it's not. If it were then you would have $ea = a$.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it is only a group if $e=a$. But when making a table we always assume the elements are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=e$, then what you have is an artificially inflated multiplication table of a single-element group. So yes, $(G,\star)$ would be a group.

Comment: By "artificially inflated", I mean that they put in duplicates of rows and columns that were already there.

Answer (score 1):

A group has three main properties: associativity of the law, existence of a neutral element and existence of an inverse for every element. Clearly the law $\star$ is associative, but what about the neutral element? Unless $e=a$, $\star$ is not a group law.

Comment: Exactly! But what if I assume $e=a$.

Comment: Then your group is the trivial group, and the table looks wrong as $e$ and $a$ seem to be two distinct elements.

Comment: I have a very good grasp of groups now (according to our syllabus)!

Answer (score 1):

If $a=e$ then G is a trivial group. If $a\neq e$ then G is not a group. For, suppose G is a group. From the table, $$e \star e=e=e \star a$$ Now cancellation gives $a=e$, which is a contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Every row and column of a group-multiplication-table is a permutation of 
all group elements, here e and a. Only e-a or a-e is possible as a row or column.

Comment: A lot of good answers! I do not know which one to check mark.